# How to pass table name if the value is string in sql query

Tags: c#

```
private void Save_rec_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pattern = ("[\\s]+");
    string input = firstname.Text;
    string replacement = "_";
    Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
    string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
    msg.Text = result;

    cmd = new SqlCeCommand("create table " + result + "(id int, first_name nVarChar(100))", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd = new SqlCeCommand("insert into '"+ result +"' values(1,'" + firstname.Text + "')", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Have you got problem in your insert statement..?

Comment: This isn't a question.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but there's too much to address in the space allowed to just commenting.  First off, who is the end-user for this code?  Is it purely internal and tightly restricted?  Because you are exposing yourself to [SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx) attacks.

That said, it looks to perform the operations you are wanting (creating a table, then inserting one row into that table), that you will have to do so using dynamic SQL as you are doing above, with the caveat that you will have to sanitize the heck out of `firstname.Text` before you include it in your SQL string. Also, for the `insert` string, you should bracket the table name with `[` and `]` not `'` and `'`.

**NOTE:** One important thing to consider is what you are trying to accomplish.  For whatever you are after, I cannot really imagine a scenario where N number of tables with a single row for N firstname inputs is a good design.

Comment: I think the code he has wont work because he is creating a table with 2 columns, but only inserting 1 column of data. Maybe he meant to make id an IDENTITY column? I agree with your assessment. This architecture is not good.

Comment: @AndrewR He's inserting a static 1 for his `id` column and the SQL-injection-vulnerable `firstname.Text` for his `first_name` column, so his syntax is alright. But there are still many problems beyond syntax.

Comment: The Regex is actually replacing multiple consecutive whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) with one underscore.  Using `Replace(' ', '_')` will only replace spaces and if there are multiple spaces in a row you get multiple underscores instead of a single underscore.

Comment: @juharr Thanks -- I had a feeling I was getting that wrong. Amended.

Answer (score 0):

One could not tell this too often, especially because it's fairly easy in .NET.
Simply prevent SQL injections from happening by using the SqlCommand Parameters like this:

```
string strUserInput = TextBox1.Text;

SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();
sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT SomeColumn FROM Table WHERE Name = @ParamName";
SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ParamName", strUserInput);
```